# Affiliation of inventor in Patent

Tags: inventorship

Consider a scenario that I had worked on the invention while I was working in the organization 'X'. However, after working on the invention with my colleagues and drafting the patent, I moved on to organization 'Y'. Organization 'Y' is completely different from organization 'X'. Subsequently, after a few months,  the patent was filed by the organization 'X' while I am no longer in that organization X.

If my name is mentioned as one of the inventors/co-inventors in the patent filed by organization 'X', what should be my affiliation be mentioned in the patent?

Should it be

1. Organization X: since the complete work regarding the invention happened here,
2. Organization Y: Since this is where I am currently working although, this organization has nothing to do with the patent?

In summary, which affiliation of the inventor should be mentioned in the patent: his/her current organization, or the organization where he had worked in the invention, considering the fact that he has changed his organization before the patent was formally filed?

If possible, can someone please also redirect me to some of provisions of Indian Patent rules which say something about this?

Answer (score 1):

You ask about Indian patent rules, and I'm US based so I'll answer from my experience. In the US and other countries I'm experienced with (mostly European), the inventor's affiliation is not noted on the patent document. The inventors are listed with their location of residence. The assignee, if a company, is listed. I have been an inventor of patents where I consulted, but again, the only organization listed is the assignee which is the organization which owns the patent.

I did manage to review a few Indian patent application documents and inventors were indeed listed by organization. The information heading is "Address" so that suggests the inventor's current affiliation, but that's just my guess. Hopefully another contributor can answer your question authoritatively.